# Amazon Cloudwatch Logs Insights

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I have to find the results in cloud watch log insights and below are the fields in logs :

```
Field   Value
@ingestionTime  
1681410599635
@log    
875721534563:ftp_Logs
@logStream  
server
@message    
MDTM|13/04/2023 06:29:57 PM|[SFTP:2547246_0:abc:x.x.x.x] READ: *fileExists /abc/xyz.txt:true*
@timestamp  
1681410598624
```

I  tried using

```
fields @timestamp, @message, @logStream, @log 
| filter @message="abc"
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 2000
```

but not getting any results , if can help in parsing or filtering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filter @message="abc"` finds the logs where the entire message is literally `abc` and nothing else.

What you want is `filter @message like "abc"`. See [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_QuerySyntax.html#CWL_QuerySyntax-regex).

Comment: Thank you so much and pointing to right direction and docu